# View state at fragment on backstack with retaininstance = true

Tags: android, view, fragment, state

I have got loader in fragment and it loads data on background. After data are loaded, I fill edittexts with that informations. Problem is that if user changes something in edittexts and rotate screen, onLoadFinished is called again and edittexts are replaced with loaded information. I solve this by adding help variable, if data was already loaded .. But when i replace this fragment with other, rotate screen back and forth and press back button, edittexts are empty. Fragment is set to retain instance true. It looks like views lost its state when fragment is on backstack. Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the retain state.
But the proper way to do so it to save the save using the Bundle and restore it when you recreate the activity (onCreate Bundle is not new).

Please review the link I've sent you it includes a very specific example.

from the android dev guide:

> To properly handle a restart, it is important that your activity
>   restores its previous state through the normal Activity lifecycle, in
>   which Android calls onSaveInstanceState() before it destroys your
>   activity so that you can save data about the application state. You
>   can then restore the state during onCreate() or
>   onRestoreInstanceState().

[Android Rotation Change](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Why i shouldnt use it? Set retaining instance is very helpful imho and i want to use that functionality